# Using StreamReader and StreamWriter to Modify Files

Tags: c#, file-io, ssis, streamreader, streamwriter

I am trying to use StreamReader and StreamWriter to Open a text file (fixed width) and to modify a few specific columns of data. I have dates with the following format that are going to be converted to packed COMP-3 fields.

```
020100718F
020100716F
020100717F
020100718F
020100719F
```

I want to be able to read in the dates form a file using StreamReader, then convert them to packed fields (5 characters), and then output them using StreamWriter. However, I haven't found a way to use StreamWriter to right to a specific position, and beginning to wonder if is possible.

I have the following code snip-it.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writer;

this.fileName = @"C:\Test9.txt";
reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(this.fileName));

currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
currentLine = currentLine.Substring(30, 10);    //Substring Containing the Date
reader.Close();

...
// Convert currentLine to Packed Field 
...

writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.File.Open(this.fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open));
writer.Write(currentLine);
```

Currently what I have does the following:

```
After:
!@#$%0718F
020100716F
020100717F
020100718F
020100719F 

!@#$% = Ascii Characters SO can't display
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Information on Packed Fields COMP-3

Packed Fields are used by COBOL systems to reduce the number of bytes a field requires in files. Please see the following SO post for more information: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974091/sql-how-to-get-comp-3-packed-decimal)

Here is Picture of the following date "20120123" packed in COMP-3. This is my end result and I have included because I wasn't sure if it would effect possible answers.

[image: Picture of the following date 20120123 packed]

My question is how do you get StreamWriter to dynamically replace data inside a file and change the lengths of rows?

Comment: I can't seem to locate what your actual question is. It might help if you explain what a packed COMP-3 data field is.  Might also help if you tell us the expected results.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: After BCD encoding you'll get **binary** data. Don't use StreamWriter to write it to file, use FileStream instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always found it better to to read the input file, filter/process the data and write the output to a temporary file. After finished, delete the original file (or make a backup) and copy the temporary file over. This way you haven't lost half your input file in case something goes wrong in the middle of processing.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using a Stream directly (probably a `FileStream`). This would allow you to change position.

However, you're not going to be able to change record sizes this way, at least, not in-line. You can have one Stream reading from the original file, and another writing to a new, converted copy of the file.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I haven't found a way to use StreamWriter to right to a specific position, and 
>   beginning to wonder if is possible.

You can use [StreamWriter.BaseStream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method

```
using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(File.Create(@"c:\Temp\aaa.txt")))
{
   wr.Write("ABC");
   wr.Flush();
   wr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   wr.Write("Z");                
}
```

Comment: That can be problematic depending on the encoding. You have to be careful not to position into the middle of a multi-byte character.

Comment: -1 There are other issues like `Flush`. try this:  `StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(File.Create(@"c:\temp\aaa.txt"));
            wr.Write("ABC");
            wr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            wr.Write("Z");
            wr.Close();` output won't be ZBC